# spread key-values across multiple columns with python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to transpose df into df_spread.

```
import pandas

df = {"Type": ("A", "B", "B", "C","D"),
      "Amount":(220, 68, 1400, 120, 99)
}

df = pandas.DataFrame(df)
```

The output I want would be like this:

```
df_spread =  {"A": 220, "B": 68, "B": 1400, "C": 120, "D": 99
}

df_spread = pandas.DataFrame(df_spread)
```

I know that a wide dataframe like this isn't the best practice, but I'm going to concatenate df with a bunch of other dataframes.

Comment: Because your second code example does not create a valid dataframe, it's hard to know exactly what you want as output. Are you just looking for `df.transpose()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can

```py
>>> df.set_index('Type').T
Type      A   B     B    C   D
Amount  220  68  1400  120  99
```

(Possibly followed by some index renaming, but if you're going to concatenate with other dfs, chances are you'll probably ignore the index anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame(df['Amount']).T
df_out.columns = df['Type']
```

Output:

```
      A    B    B   C   D
0   220   68 1400 120  99
```